# How to print the predicted values using zip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm using decision tree and getting a 78% score but how can i print the predicted values

I've tried

```
for X,Y in zip(X_test, y_test):
    print("Model:", dt.predict([X][0]), "actual:", y)
```

but it is showing an error which says

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>   single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


df = pd.read_csv("final interview.csv")
df = sklearn.utils.shuffle(df)
df = df.drop(["position", "department"], axis=1)

X = df.drop("decision", axis=1).values
y = df["decision"].values

test_size = 20
X_train = X[:-test_size]
y_train = y[:-test_size]

X_test = X[-test_size:]
y_test = y[-test_size:]

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(dt.score(X_test, y_test))


for X,Y in zip(X_test, y_test):
    print("Model:", dt.predict([X][0]), "actual:", y)
```

I expect the `predicted values  :  actual values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your print be like this:

```
for X,Y in zip(dt.predict(X_test),y_test):
    print("Model Score:", X, "actual score:", Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your solution, You need to write the below code:-

```
pred=dt.predict(X_test).tolist()
y_test=y_test.tolist()
for X,Y in zip(pred, y_test):
    print("Model:", X, "actual:", Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a list comprehension like below:

```
print(["Pred : {} True class: {}".format(dt.predict([x]),y) for x,y in zip(X_test, y_test)])
```